# Python - Specific Files Denied Permission

Tags: python, permissions

I am trying to loop through 22 .txt files in a directory, read each lines from the file, and apply some conditions, before writing the modified lines in a newly created file in a different folder.

The issue is that the first 12 files are successfully created, but then I get a permission denied error for all subsequent files. The permissions for the files that fail are the exact same ones as the one that succeed.

Here is a simplified version of my code, excluding a bunch of if conditions for simplicity:

```
files =  os.listdir('./folder/')
for file in files:
    with open('./folder/' + file, "r") as input:
        with open('./folder/mod/' + file[:-4] + '_mod.txt', "w") as output:
            lines = input.readlines()
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                if lines[i][-7:-1] != '    },':
                    output.write('\n' + lines[i][:-4].replace('"',''))
        output.close()
    input.close()
```

I have tried to exclude the first 12 files completely from the source folder, and then not a single file gets written. As if the issue really lies with the .txt files themselves. These files were all generated at the same time, and are fairly simple, so I can't pinpoint any difference between them.

Here is the Stack Trace returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\Documents\project1\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    with open('./folder/' + file, "r") as input:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './folder/mod'
```

***EDIT
If I leave only 1 file that was successfully read and written in the source folder, the operation is successful but I still get the same permission denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace says the problem is that:

```
`with open('./folder/' + file, "r") as input:`
```

is trying to open and read "folder/mod/"

os.listdir() will create a list of everything in a folder, including directories.
So since you can't "read" a directory, python is giving you a permission error.

Adding a test to see if the "file" in the for loop is actually a file should solve the problem: